# Polar contour plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I have a set of data that I want to use to produce a contour plot in polar co-ordinates using Matplotlib.

My data is the following:

- `theta` - 1D array of angle values
- `radius` - 1D array of radius values
- `value` - 1D array of values that I want to use for the contours

These are all 1D arrays that align properly - eg:

```
theta   radius   value
30      1        2.9
30      2        5.3
35      5        9.2
```

That is, all of the values are repeated enough times so that each row of this 'table' of three variables defines one point.

How can I create a polar contour plot from these values? I've thought about converting the radius and theta values to x and y values and doing it in cartesian co-ordinates, but the contour function seems to require 2D arrays, and I can't quite understand why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matplotlib's `contour()` function expects data to be arranged as a 2D grid of points and corresponding grid of values for each of those grid points.  If your data is naturally arranged in a grid you can convert r, theta to x, y and use `contour(r*np.cos(theta), r*np.sin(theta), values)` to make your plot.

If your data isn't naturally gridded, you should follow Stephen's advice and used `griddata()` to interpolate your data on to a grid.

The following script shows examples of both.

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy as np

# data on a grid
r = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r, t = np.meshgrid(r, t)
z = (t-np.pi)**2 + 10*(r-0.5)**2

plt.subplot(121)
plt.contour(r*np.cos(t), r*np.sin(t), z)

# ungrid data, then re-grid it
r = r.flatten()
t = t.flatten()
x = r*np.cos(t)
y = r*np.sin(t)
z = z.flatten()
xgrid = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
ygrid = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
zgrid = griddata(x,y,z, xgrid, ygrid)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.contour(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer. I've posted a follow-up question about axes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556361/add-polar-axes-to-cartesian-plot-in-matplotlib. I wonder if you might be able to help with that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's possible to do a polar contour plot directly, but if you convert to cartesian coordinates you can use the [`griddata`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.griddata) function to convert your 1D arrays to 2D.