# Finding angle using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am fairly new to using matplotlib and cannot find any examples that show how to mark the angle of a point. I need to find the angle in all four quadrants i.e. if the point is (1,1) angle=45 degrees, (-1,1) angle= 135 degrees, (-1,-1) angle=225 degrees and for (1,-1) it should be 315 degrees.

Here is the function to which i need to add this to:

```
def visualize(val,ar):
   plt.figure()
   ax = plt.gca()
   ax.plot([val-5],[ar-5], marker='o', color='r')
   ax.set_xlim([-5,5])
   ax.set_ylim([-5,5])
   plt.draw()
   plt.grid()
   plt.show()
```

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556361/add-polar-axes-to-cartesian-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: This is not, fundamentally, a *matplotlib* question. Eventually you may need to write the angle on the plot, for which you will use `matplotlib.pyplot.text` (equivalent to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`). Until you get there, this is a *geometry* question. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265695/finding-the-exact-values-of-trig-functions-in-a-quadrant) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352655/question-on-inverse-trig-functions-and-quadrants-please-help). Those are not exact answers to your problem, but provide good hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the maths on your points yourself and then annotate the points on the plot using [`annotate()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate). It's hard to tell from your example whether `val` and `ar` are single values or vectors - I think single values given the syntax you're using.  Here's an example with a function to do the maths and an example use of `annotate` - I've tried to keep the plotting bits the same as your code and just add the bits to calculate degrees and then put them on the axes

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#This function does the maths - turns co-ordinates into angles
#with 0 on +ve x axis, increasing anti-clockwise
def get_theta(x,y):
    theta = math.atan(y*1.0/x) / (2*math.pi) * 360
    if x < 0:
        theta += 180
    if theta < 0:
        theta += 360
    return theta 

def visualize(val,ar):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot([val-5],[ar-5], marker='o', color='r')
    ax.set_xlim([-5,5])
    ax.set_ylim([-5,5])
   #insert the following to calculate the angles and
   #then annotate them on the plot
    x,y = val-5,ar-5
    label = get_theta(x, y)
    ax.annotate(str(label)+' degrees', xy = (x, y), xytext = (-20, 20),textcoords = 'offset points')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.figure()
    x = [6,4,4,6]
    y = [6,6,4,4]
    for (val, ar) in zip(x,y):
        visualize(val,ar)    

    plt.draw()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Further variations on what you can do with annotations are [in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

---

#### Output

[image: Picture of graph with the example points annotated]

Comment: @Code_aholic does this do what you want?  If there are any issues - feel free to leave a comment and we can probably address.  Otherwise - if you're not sure what to do to mark the question resolved, please see [what to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)