# How can I draw a scatter plot with contour density lines in polar coordinates using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to make a scatter plot in **polar coordinates** with the contour lines superposed to the cloud of points. I am aware of how to do that in cartesian coordinates using `numpy.histogram2d`:

```
# Simple case: scatter plot with density contours in cartesian coordinates

import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 1000
shift_value = -6.

x1 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
y1 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value

fig, ax = pl.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)

ax.scatter(x1,y1,color='hotpink')

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1,y1)
extent = [xedges[0],xedges[-1],yedges[0],yedges[-1]]
cset1 = ax.contour(H,extent=extent)

# Modify xlim and ylim to be a bit more consistent with what's next
ax.set_xlim(xmin=-10.,xmax=+10.)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=-10.,ymax=+10.)
```

Output is here:

[image: correct_output_cartesian]

However, when I try to transpose my code to polar coordinates I get distorted contour lines. Here is my code and the produced (wrong) output:

```
# Case with polar coordinates; the contour lines are distorted

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 1000
shift_value = -6.

def CartesianToPolar(x,y):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    theta = np.arctan2(y,x)

    return theta, r

x2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
y2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value

theta2, r2 = CartesianToPolar(x2,y2)

fig2 = pl.figure()
ax2 = pl.subplot(projection="polar")
ax2.scatter(theta2, r2, color='hotpink')

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2,y2)


theta_edges, r_edges = CartesianToPolar(xedges[:-1],yedges[:-1])
ax2.contour(theta_edges, r_edges,H)
```

The *wrong* output is here:

[image: wrong_output_polar]

Is there any way to have the contour lines at the proper scale?

EDIT to address suggestions made in comments.

EDIT2: Someone suggested that the question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548556/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib). Although I recognize that the problems are similar, mine deals specifically with plotting the density contours of points over a scatter plot. The other question is about how to plot the contour levels of any quantity that is specified along with the coordinates of the points.

Comment: Hi, it might be helpful to keep the shift value constant between the two plots to make the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: Sure, you're right, it's done !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polar contour plot in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548556/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9071084/1461210

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you're only converting the edges of the array.  By converting only the x and y coordinates of the edges, you're effectively converting the coordinates of a diagonal line across the 2D array.  This line has a very small range of `theta` values, and you're applying that range to the entire grid.

### The quick (but incorrect) fix

In most cases, you could convert the entire grid (i.e. 2D arrays of `x` and `y`, producing 2D arrays of `theta` and `r`) to polar coordinates.

Instead of:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2,y2)
theta_edges, r_edges = CartesianToPolar(xedges[:-1],yedges[:-1])
```

Do something similar to:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2,y2)
xedges, yedges = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1],yedges[:-1]
theta_edges, r_edges = CartesianToPolar(xedges, yedges)
```

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    x2, y2 = generate_data()
    theta2, r2 = cart2polar(x2,y2)

    fig2 = plt.figure()
    ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")
    ax2.scatter(theta2, r2, color='hotpink')

    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2,y2)

    xedges, yedges = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])
    theta_edges, r_edges = cart2polar(xedges, yedges)
    ax2.contour(theta_edges, r_edges, H)

    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    np.random.seed(2015)
    N = 1000
    shift_value = -6.

    x2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
    y2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
    return x2, y2

def cart2polar(x,y):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    theta = np.arctan2(y,x)

    return theta, r

main()
```

[image]

However, you may notice that this looks slightly incorrect.  That's because `ax.contour` implicitly assumes that the input data is on a regular grid.  We've given it a regular grid in cartesian coordinates, but not a regular grid in polar coordinates.  It's assuming we've passed it a regular grid in polar coordinates.  We could resample the grid, but there's an easier way.

### The correct solution

To correctly plot the 2D histogram, compute the histogram in polar space.

For example, do something similar to:

```
theta2, r2 = cart2polar(x2,y2)
H, theta_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta2, r2)
ax2.contour(theta_edges[:-1], r_edges[:-1], H)
```

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    x2, y2 = generate_data()
    theta2, r2 = cart2polar(x2,y2)

    fig2 = plt.figure()
    ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")
    ax2.scatter(theta2, r2, color='hotpink')

    H, theta_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta2, r2)
    ax2.contour(theta_edges[:-1], r_edges[:-1], H)

    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    np.random.seed(2015)
    N = 1000
    shift_value = -6.

    x2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
    y2 = np.random.randn(N) + shift_value
    return x2, y2

def cart2polar(x,y):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    theta = np.arctan2(y,x)

    return theta, r

main()
```

[image]

Finally, you might notice a slight shift in the above result.  This has to do with cell-oriented grid conventions (`x[0,0], y[0,0]` gives the center of the cell) vs edge-oriented grid conventions (`x[0,0], y[0,0]` gives the lower-left corner of the cell.  `ax.contour` is expecting things to be cell-centered, but you're giving it edge-aligned x and y values.

It's only a half-cell shift, but if you'd like to fix it, do something like:

```
def centers(bins):
    return np.vstack([bins[:-1], bins[1:]]).mean(axis=0)

H, theta_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta2, r2)
theta_centers, r_centers = centers(theta_edges), centers(r_edges)

ax2.contour(theta_centers, r_centers, H)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my initial problem !
However, when I apply it to real (non gaussian) data, the density contour lines are slightly shifted with respect to the position of the points. Are you aware of this problem?